# Schengen visa application - too many emails to consulate

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, consulates

I have applied for a Schengen visa at the French consulate, Miami. I am an Indian student in the U.S. I have previously obtained a visa from the same consulate (w years ago), as well as previous Schengen visas elsewhere. I love travelling and have a travel history from 23+ countries throughout my life. I am not too worried about my background or documentation. I am planning a trip to France and Italy on the way home for my summer break.

However, while processing was taking place, my flight back from India to the US got cancelled by the airline due to scheduling changes. I rebooked, but not sure for how long my reservation was cancelled. I immediately emailed the new flight details to the consulate. I thought that my emails did not reach them, so I sent them the mail 4 times in a span of 15 minutes from different accounts. To one of my emails, they responded:

> Hi,
>
> We have received this e-mail 3 times already, and a flight between
>   India, the UK and the US has nothing to do with the French Consulate.
>
> Please stop sending it.

I understand that I have pissed off the consulate. Should I send an apology email to make it clear that no malice was intended, or should I let it be? Will this exchange do ill to my application?

Thanks,
Ansh

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't get it either, just like the French Consulate - could you let us know what you sent the consulate for a flight from India to the US to the French consulate? What does this flight have to do with your planned trip to France?

Comment: Step away from the keyboard and just respond to any queries they have from this point onward.  Do not send any unsolicited emails or comments. Do not pass go. Do not collect $200.

Comment: Also, while we're asking questions, why did you think your emails didn't reach them? Sending an email repeatedly within 15 minutes from different accounts is not a normal usage of email, and I'm not understanding why you thought that to be necessary, even if you were sending them something they cared about.

Comment: Hi, to respond to the comments:
I am a student in the US and they want proof that I have a reason to return to the US to continue my education - so I provided a ticket from India to the US after my summer break.

Comment: I have noticed in the past that some of my emails I send to them receive an immediate autoresponse saying email received or so, and some don't. The emails they actually reply to are only out of those which previously received the autoresponse, making me think that some of my emails end up in their spam and are never seen. So I decided to send multiple emails. 
The ones I sent with this new ticket initially did not receive an immediate autoresponse, so I sent the emails again. However, they DID receive an autoresponse in 10 min - it was morning 9:00 so probably a busy time for their server.

Comment: @Ansh airplane tickets are disposable, they are rarely considered proof of your intention to exit a country when a visa application is considered - if they were taken as proof to an extent which tips any balance, then visitors planning overstaying wouldnt think twice about buying a $2000 ticket they never intend to use if that means they get to stay in a country where they could earn $30,000.  When countries ask for an onward bound ticket, its generally so they have a way to throw you out of the country without any expenditure to them - so you dont become a burden on state funds.

Comment: Don't send another message.  The person fielding the messages probably has nothing to do with deciding the visa application anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, so I will resist the urge to respond an apology. I pick up my passport on Tuesday - let's see if they issue the visa!

Comment: I am aware the tickets do not represent a true proof of leaving however they are still an integral component of a visa application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not worry about it, and there is no need to contact them further concerning the email exchange. 
However-- if the reason that you need to contact them is to change the dates of your visa (especially your entry date), send them an email with the subject "Change of Dates to [[Type of Visa]][[Last Name, First Name]] [[Application # if you have one]]" or visit their office in person to discuss the status of your application.

Happy Travels.